# are the class attributes stored as a tuple here?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Example:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank

class Deck:
        def __init__(self):
            self.all_cards = []
            for suit in suits:
                for rank in ranks:
                    self.all_cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
```

Can someone please explain how the class attributes for Card stored as? When I access the card class in Deck are the attributes retrieved as a tuple?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029249/python-dict or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/explain-dict-attribute

Comment: The `Card` objects are stored in a **list** of `d.all_cards` where `d` is an instance of `Deck`. Each card object's attributes are stored in the instance dictionary (`c.__dict__` where `c` is an instance of `Card`).